# Splitting strings with RegEx to match ampersand only when not surrounded by pluses

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'm trying to split a query param string on `&`s, as long as the ampersand doesn't have `+`s around it, but can't seem to get the RegEx right. My desired output for the example below is `["brand=dolce+&+gabbana", "gender=male"]`.

This is what I've tried:

```
str = "brand=dolce+&+gabbana&gender=male"
str.split(/&[^+&+]/g)
```

This returns `["brand=dolce+&+gabbana", "ender=male"]` which is close, but not quite right since the "g" in "gender" is getting matched as well. How can I ensure only the ampersands are matched?

Comment: You might use [`/(?<!\+)&(?!\+)/`](https://regex101.com/r/p6O1GO/1) if your JS environment is ECMAScript 2018 compatible. You might always try [`str.match(/(?:\+&\+|[^&])+/g)`](https://regex101.com/r/p6O1GO/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/\b&\b/` works:

```js
str = "brand=dolce+&+gabbana&gender=male"
console.log(str.split(/\b&\b/g))
```